# How to disable Elmah memory logging?

Tags: asp.net, logging, elmah

We're using Elmah in an asp.net 2.0 web app. Is there a way to disable the default Memory Log provider? In other words, we're logging to SQL Server and because of this we want to completely eliminate the MemoryErrorLog provider that is true by default.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Why do you think Elmah is logging to memory even without corresponding line in its config?

Comment: How do you know it is still logging to memory even though the it isn't stated in the config file?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove this line from your `web.config`:

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.MemoryErrorLog, Elmah" size="50" />
```

Comment: That line is not present in my web.config. I've setup <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah" /> but the Elmah is still logging to memory IN ADDITION to the SQL db.